# sqlalchemy materialized relationships

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, materialized-views

I have a data model which is analogous to the following:

```
Location 1-----*<> Vacation <>*------1 TravelAgency
                     <>
                     |*
                     |
                     |1
                  Airline
```

It is implemented in sqlalchemy in the normal way:

```
class Vacation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'vacation'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('location.id')
    location = relationship("Location")
    travel_agency_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('travel_agency.id')
    travel_agency = relationship("TravelAgency")
    airline_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('airline.id')
    airline = relationship("Airline")

class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Integer)

class TravelAgency(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'travel_agency'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Integer)

class Airline(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'airline'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Integer)
```

Analysis of vacations in a database of hundreds of millions of objects is too slow due to the multiple joins required. After exhausting my options for speeding up the join operations with database configuration options, I am now trying to use database triggers to maintain a materialized view of vacations joined with its aggregates.

```
SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE table_name = 'vacation_materialized';

 column_name  
--------------
id
location_id
location$data
travel_agency_id
travel_agency$data
airline_id
airline$data
```

Now I am weighing options for how to reconstruct vacation, travel_agency and airline objects from this view. One option is to use the sqlalchemy core to query the vacation_materialized table then parse the rows and construct the objects "by hand". Are there any ORM features I should be looking into that might result in a more "elegant" solution?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do map a class against the materialized view, then provide read-only Relationship properties:

```
materialized_vacations = Table('materialized_vacations', metadata, autoload=True)
locations = Table('locations', metadata, autoload=True)

mvac_2_location = materialized_vacations.c.location_id==locations.c.location_id

class Location(Base):
    __table__ = locations

class MaterializedVacation(Base):
    __table__ = materialized_vacations
    location = relationship("Location", primaryjoin=mvac_2_location, viewonly=True)
    ...
```

I'm assuming here that you *don't* want to put any Foreign Keys into your materialized view. Instead, I'm specifying the join conditions explicitly using the `primaryjoin` keyword argument to `relationship()`.

Here `mvac_2_location` creates an `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.BinaryExpression`; I like to declare those separately before using because they tend to take up most of a line on their own and make argument sequences unreadable if they're declared where they're used. It also makes them reusable and importable into submodules, which can be handy.

To construct `mvac_2_location`, I need the actual table objects, and I need them before finishing declaration of class `MaterializedVacation`, so I'm declaring them the old-fashioned pre-declarative way and then binding the classes to the tables using the declarative argument `__table__` in place of the more common `__tablename__`. It's possible that there's a better way to do that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but I don't think this gets at what I am going for. I have "cached" my joins in a secondary table. I would like to be able to query an alternate mapping to that secondary table which would improve performance by minimizing joins. You solution seems to still require joining the primary tables. I believe the solution involves CompositeProperty rather than a RelationshipProperty. My attempt at that solution is described [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342525/sqlalchemy-compositeproperty-for-a-mapped-type). Is this a sensible thing to want to do?